# brightscript: prevent RowList from looping through its content - stop at the last item

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

Brightscript's RowList has a nice feature: when it contains 5 items and more, it does not stop at the last one, when scrolling, but it brings the first one from the right and so on in a loop.

My problem is that I have to present a limited number of items (e.g., 10), but have RowList to stop at the very last one (no right move) and at the very first one (no left move).

The RowList also handles the left and the right key events, so it is impossible to override this behavior.

Does anyone know how to have RowList to behave so?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

`rowFocusAnimationStyle="floatingFocus"` in RowList

The focus indicator will stay fixed on the first or last item in the row